# Is this normal? No idea what's going on

Tags: updates, kubuntu

I tried updating my laptop with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrad`e and I got the error `unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing`. This started happening after I successfully updated my system 30 or so minutes ago. Running sudo apt upgrade `--fix-missing` gives `failed to fetch` error.

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, copy the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com//help/formatting).

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question and add more detail. What command did you run? Are you connected to the internet? Did you run `sudo apt update` first? The more you tell us, the likelier it is we will be able to help :)

Comment: I tried sudo apt update and then sudo apt upgrade.  Running autoremove --purge  seem to have fixed the issue.

Comment: At the time you ran this command, the server at `security.ubuntu.com` could not serve the requested files. This is usually very temporary - merely trying it again may have helped. In any case, your answer is probably not a solution.